# My Windows Server Has IP Address That We Don't Know How Its added

Tags: interface

We use windows server 2016. We were checking our ip list and found one ip that has a ssh connection open but not related any of out linux servers.

We looks hours to determine which server is using it. Finally, we found that our windows servers use it by looking mac address of the server that use this ip.

I didnt believe it because we didnt assing that ip on the windows server. Checked all interfaces and nope ip isnt assigned.

However, **we lost ssh connection when we pull of the server ethernet connection.** Thus, Windows server use this ip with ssh connection.

We couldnt determine which application use it so we need help to find it.

```
netstat -r
===========================================================================
Interface List
  3...34 17 eb ec 62 0a ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  5...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   185.xxx.xxx.81   185.xxx.xxx.89    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
   185.xxx.xxx.80  255.255.255.240         On-link    185.xxx.xxx.89    281
   185.xxx.xxx.89  255.255.255.255         On-link    185.xxx.xxx.89    281
   185.xxx.xxx.95  255.255.255.255         On-link    185.xxx.xxx.89    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    185.xxx.xxx.89    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    185.xxx.xxx.89    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   185.xxx.xxx.81  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  5    331 ::/0                     On-link
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  5    331 2001::/32                On-link
  5    331 2001:0:9d38:6abd:c08:35e9:4681:4da6/128
                                    On-link
  3    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  5    331 fe80::/64                On-link
  5    331 fe80::c08:35e9:4681:4da6/128
                                    On-link
  3    281 fe80::25e0:27ac:2c3:39ba/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  3    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  5    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: This sounds like an out of band management interface of some kind... ILO, iDRAC, etc.

Comment: Your question is not clear. However if you need to find out which local process is bound to a specific socket you can run netstat -b